# didSet leads to EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: swift, exc-bad-access

If I use this:

```
fileprivate var _saved = false
    open var lat = 0.0 {
        didSet {
            _saved = false
        }
   }
```

leads to EXC_BAD_ACCESS

for

`moobj.lat = 0.0`

but simple `open var lat = 0.0` looks fine. no errors.
Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After few hours and several rebuilds/restart the problem dissapeared. Don't know the reason. Imo, bug of XCode.

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer is here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AccessControl.html

Look in particular at the section entitled "Guiding Principle of Access Levels" which contains the following two points:

i. A public variable cannot be defined as having an internal, file-private, or private type, because the type might not be available everywhere that the public variable is used.

ii. A function cannot have a higher access level than its parameter types and return type, because the function could be used in situations where its constituent types are not available to the surrounding code.

I think your code falls foul of the second proviso, as the parameter for the didSet observer function is open but the function itself is trying to change a fileprivate variable.